# Get random results from MySQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want the different results in the same cell.

My code:

```
include 'config/connection.php';
$sql=$con->query("SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY RAND() ");
$teams=$sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $i=0;
if ($sql){
        while ($teams=$sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $logo=$teams['logo'];
            $team=$teams['team'];
           echo "<tr>
                  <td>
                   <h4 class=\"ui image header\"><img src=\"$logo\" class=\"ui mini rounded image\">
                    <img src=\"$logo\" class=\"ui mini rounded image\">
                    <div class=\"content\">
                     $team<br>$team
                    </div>
                   </h4>
                  </td>
                </tr>";
               }
              ?>
```

Although the above code produces the same results in the same cell. How can I randomize it??? E.g. I want to get the different teams in the same cell, but not similar teams.

Comment: PHP post-processing may re-order records. Use the method (mysqli_fetch_row ?) which do not perform additional records processing.

Comment: can you post the table structure,the result you are getting now & desired result ?

Comment: You can shuffle array in PHP instead MySQL

Comment: at `$team<br>$team` am getting mci and mci.what i want is different teams there eg mci and mun